# Calling then before or after Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

Currently I have following code:

```
var detailPromises = links.map(function (link) { return requestP(link) });

var oldPollNames = [];
// add a database call to the promises as it also can resolved during detail fetching
detailPromises.push(db.polls.findAsync({}, {title: 1}));
return Promise.all(detailPromises)
    .then(function (data) {
        oldPollNames = data.pop().map(function (item) { return item.title; });
        return data;
    })
    .then(function (htmls) {
        var newPolls = [];
        htmls.forEach(function (i, html) {
            // some processing of html using oldPollNames (newPools.push...)
        });
        return newPolls;
    })
    .then(/* insert into db */);
```

What I'm doing is: waiting for db + waiting for html requests and then process booth.

I'm wondering if it would make more sense / be more performant to do following:

```
var detailPromises = links.map(function (link) { return requestP(link) });

return db.polls.findAsync({}, {title: 1}).then(function(polls) {
    var oldPollNames = polls.map(function (item) { return item.title; });
    var newPolls = [];

    detailPromises = detailPromises.map(function (p) {
        return p.then(function (html) {
            // some processing of html using oldPollNames (newPools.push...)
        })
    });

    return Promise.all(detailPromises)
        .done(function () {
            // insert newPolls into db
        });
});
```

The advantage of the second approach imo is that each request gets (already) handled when it is done and can do it's procesing before all / other promises are fulfilled.

Comment: What promise library are you using? What is `.done`?

Comment: You really should be using `map` instead of `forEach` and the `newPolls`  array.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, otherwise Promise.all would not wait for all processing (newPools.push...) to be done. Thx

Comment: @Bergi done is used on https://www.promisejs.org/ But I actually have no clue why they use it *lol*

Comment: Ah, I see. [They say](https://www.promisejs.org/#done): "*Note that promise.done (used as a teaching aid in the examples in this section) has not been standardised.*". You shouldn't use it, always go for `then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it would make more sense / be more performant

Yes, it would be more performant to process each html request separately and as fast as possible, instead of waiting for all of them and then processing them together in a huge loop. Not only will they processed earlier, you also avoid a possibly long-running loop of heavy processing.

However, the approach also has its drawbacks: it's more complicated to implement. The code you've given is prone to reporting `Unhandled Rejection`s if any of the `detailPromises` rejects before the database query fulfills, or if any of them rejects and the database query is rejected as well. To prevent that, you'll need to use `Promise.all` on all the promises anyway:

```
var detailPromises = links.map(requestP);

var resultPromise = db.polls.findAsync({}, {title: 1}).then(function(polls) {
    var oldPollNames = polls.map(function(item) { return item.title; });
    var newPollPromises = detailPromises.map(function(p, i) {
        return p.then(function(html) {
            // some processing of html
        });
    });

    return Promise.all(newPollPromies) // not the detailPromises!
    .then(function(newPolls) {
        // insert newPolls into db
    });
});
return Promise.all([resultPromise].concat(detailPromises)).then(function(r) {
    return r[0];
});
```

Comment: *Boarh* I really had to think hard about it but it makes perfectly sense.

Comment: Is there any way to make it nicer or put things into a function? I can't imagine one.

Comment: @velop: Make what part nicer?

Comment: I think in Bluebird you can also do `return Promise.all(detailPromises).return(resultPromise)` without having to fear unhandled rejections

Comment: Do you think it's over engineering if I do something like: http://jsbin.com/kibozusipu/edit?js,output

Comment: @velop: Yes, I think it's easier to understand without `waitForFirst`. ymmv. Choose whatever you find most readable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bergi's answer I think I found another likewise solution:

```
var detailPromises = links.map(requestP);
var pollNamePromise = db.polls.findAsync({}, {title: 1}).then(function(polls) {
        return polls.map(function (item) { return item.title; });
    });

var newPromises = detailPromises.map(function(p) {
        return Promise.join(p, pollNamePromise, function(html, oldPollNames) {
            // some processing of html using oldPollNames (newPools.push...)
        });
    });

Promise.all(newPromises).then(function(newPolls) {
    // insert newPolls into db
});
```

**Edit** Changed from Promise.all to Promise.join which is available in [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html)