# Node.js - Continue promise chain for each result after promise.all()

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am using `Promise.all()` within a promise chain. Each promise within the Promise.all() returns a string.

The issue im having is that Promise.all() [returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) object to the next promise and I would like to continue the promise chain for each string.

Heres an example:

```
....
     return Promise.all(plugins);

})
.then(function(response) {

     console.log(response)
....
```

The `response` looks like:

```
[ 'results from p1', 'results from p2' ]
```

Is there any way to continue the promise chain for each of the results rather than continuing with a single object containing all results?

Comment: Have a look at [Calling then before or after Promise.all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36594198/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all()`, by its design returns a single promise who's resolved value is an array of resolved values for all the promises you passed it.  That's what it does.  If that isn't what you want, then perhaps you are using the wrong tool.  You can process the individual results in a number of ways:

First, you can just loop over the array of returned results and do whatever you want to with them for further processing.

```
Promise.all(plugins).then(function(results) {
    return results.map(function(item) {
        // can return either a value or another promise here
        return ....
    });
}).then(function(processedResults) {
    // process final results array here
})
```

Second, you could attach a `.then()` handler to each individual promise BEFORE you pass it to `Promise.all()`.

```
// return new array of promises that has done further processing
// before passing to Promise.all()
var array = plugins.map(function(p) {
    return p.then(function(result) {
        // do further processing on the individual result here
        // return something (could even be another promise)
        return xxx;
    });
})

Promise.all(array).then(function(results) {
    // process final results array here
});
```

Or, third if you don't really care when all the results are done and you just want to process each one individually, then don't use `Promise.all()` at all.  Just attach a `.then()` handler to each individual promise and process each result as it happens.

Comment: Very helpful indeed. Thanks for the detailed options and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Promise.all expects an array of promises. So plugins is an array of promises and all the more: plugin is a Promise.
So you can just chain your plugin Promise.
This would thus become

`Promise.all(plugins.map(function(plugin){
  return plugin.then(function(yourPluginString){
    return 'example '+ yourPluginString;
  })
}))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like  https://github.com/Raising/PromiseChain

and implement what you say as

```
//sc = internalScope
var sc = {};

new PromiseChain(sc)  
    .continueAll([plugin1,plugin2,plugin3],function(sc,plugin){
       return plugin(); // I asume this return a promise
    },"pluginsResults")  
    .continueAll(sc.pluginsResults,function(sc,pluginResult){ 
       return handlePluginResults(pluginResult);
    },"operationsResults")  
.end();
```

I didnt test the code if you have any problem PM me